# How to add a null condition in CodeIgniter without quotes?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, quotes, backticks

This code:

```
$this->db->where('id_etablissement_commanditaire IS ', $_POST['id_etablissement_commanditaire'], FALSE  );
```

Gives:

```
WHERE id_etablissement_commanditaire IS NULL
```

That one:

```
$this->db->where('id_etablissement_commanditaire IS ', $_POST['id_etablissement_commanditaire']);
```

Gives:

```
WHERE `id_etablissement_commanditaire` IS 'NULL'
```

Is there a way to get :

```
    WHERE `id_etablissement_commanditaire` IS NULL
```

I.e. I would like backticks but not quotes.

Comment: I'm not sure you actually need backticks for that column name, so the first method should be fine as it is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: you are right, it's not necessary, it was to get stuck to MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if ($_POST['id_etablissement_commanditaire']) {
    $this->db->where('id_etablissement_commanditaire IS ', $_POST['id_etablissement_commanditaire']);
} else {
    $this->db->where('id_etablissement_commanditaire IS NULL', null, false)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very good ! I have a question on your code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25118132/what-does-mean-if-postid-etablissement-commanditaire

Comment: @NilsBAY you're welcome, the link you mentioned is broken, if this answer worked for your question please accept it.

Comment: @Nils, if your question is relating to this answer and is a small supplementary, just ask it here. I believe the new question was deleted by a moderator because you addressed it to Mohammed - we don't do that here - it just confused/confuses people.

Comment: Ok halfer. I would like to know if if ($_POST['id_etablissement_commanditaire']) is the same as if ($_POST['id_etablissement_commanditaire'] != '') ? or not ?

Comment: @NilsBAY it involves that case, but also all of false values whose (`null`, `0`, `empty string("" or '')`, `not set`, `false`).